# Custom Options fields position

Tags: custom-options

Can you help me how can I change the position of Custom Options on product page.
I mean: First Custom Options fields are displayed, then configurable fields.
I'm Very appreciated for your help.

Comment: What have you tried? Please give some evidence that you've put some effort into this, even if you can only post dead-end findings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the layout file of your theme `catalog.xml` you can find these lines inside the `<PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>` tag:

```
<reference name="product.info.options.wrapper">
    <block type="catalog/product_view_type_configurable" name="product.info.options.configurable" as="options_configurable" before="-" template="catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

All you need to to is to change the attribute `before="-"` to `after="-"`. So the lines above become:

```
<reference name="product.info.options.wrapper">
    <block type="catalog/product_view_type_configurable" name="product.info.options.configurable" as="options_configurable" after="-" template="catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Clear the cache and move on to your next task. :)

Comment: where can I get such info about Magento?

Comment: @user3169 you just did :). Now seriously, this is a good place to start: http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/